# How can I run hierarchy view with Nexus One

Tags: android

I am trying to debug an android app on nexus one with an hierarchy viewer. I start hierarchy view on desktop, Under 'Devices', I see my phone, but when I click 'Start Server', I see
'version = 2
protocol = 2
version = 2' on the terminal of when I start hierarchy viewer.

But nothing else happens, 'Load View Hierarchy' remains disabled.

Can you please tell me how can I get hierarchy viewer to work?

Answer (score 14):

Or include the ViewServer into your application. Then you can use the hierarchy viewer on any device. But only for your own app.

https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer

ADT version 12 required.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Mark Murphy's book](http://commonsware.com/Android/):

> > Note that you cannot use HierarchyViewer with a production Android device (e.g., T-Mobile G1)

Though, I've been able to run the HierarchyViewer on my handset after installing an unoffical ROM and rooting it. I think it voids the guarantee, though.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to unlock bootloader and root the device. Running  hierarchyViewer along totally worth the time.

Comment: It's more than just rooting the device. ro.debuggable and ro.secure need to be set to 'engineering' options. 1, and 0 respectively.